# PHP Query String issue

Tags: php, querystringparameter

I am a little green with PHP and I have a small problem I am hoping to get some help with. I am using the following query in a file and I want to add a sort order at the end. I am not sure how to escape the last part of the query to get the query to accept the sort order.

```
$queryPro = "select * from pages WHERE MenuType='S' AND Activate='Y' AND SiteID='4000' AND SubMenuOf=".$rowCat["PageNumber"];
```

What I would like to use is

```
$queryPro = "select * from pages WHERE MenuType='S' AND Activate='Y' AND SiteID='4000' AND SubMenuOf=".$rowCat["PageNumber"] Order By SortOrder ASC;
```

But this produces an error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
JW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did not include the `ORDER BY...` in the string causing syntax error,

```
$queryPro = "select...AND SubMenuOf=".$rowCat["PageNumber"] . " Order By SortOrder ASC";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you for the help and the link. I will try to implement these changes.